# Pandas Testing with Pytest - see which rows are different

Tags: python, pandas, pytest

Relatively new to actually using pytest / testing modules, so I may be missing something very obvious.

I'm using the [pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html) method in my testing, and I would like to see which row is causing the test to fail when using pytest.

I have my tests set up and they are running, I am calling `pytest` from the terminal. The output I am getting is like this

```
#other stuff, name of test that failed, etc
E   AssertionError: DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] (column name="Name") are different
E   
E   DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] (column name="Name") values are different (1.23457 %)
E   [index]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80]
E   [left]:  [Alice, Bob, ...
E   [right]: [Alice, Bob, ...

pandas\_libs\testing.pyx:167: AssertionError
============================================== short test summary info =============================================== 
FAILED tests/test_outputs.py::test_june - AssertionError: DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] (column name="Name") are different
```

It would help to know which row failed here; that is, which name in left didn't equal in right. I found myself having to separately run code to do a line-by-line comparison that printed out Names and indices...

Is there a flag on pytest or pandas that can show this in the pytest printout?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this natively, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71412691/how-to-output-all-differences-if-pandas-testing-assert-frame-equal-fails) might be helpful

Comment: that post is exactly right, the same question! failed to find it when searching...